# cyclic slideshow in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a cyclic slideshow.

I've implemented it using a RecyclerView.

**What's the most efficient way to implement this ?** 
I had an idea of storing the bitmaps themselves in SharedPreferences. Then, when scrolling, instead of loading the image url each time to a new cell and deleting from an old one.

Comment: can you put java file here?

Comment: it's just ImageViews in RecyclerView that are being loaded with the image url.

Comment: please put your code

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: you have implemented my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsData.size();
    }
```

from

```
 @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
```

Comment: you must give the condition for that whenever recyclerview item is at last position than you must set to zero position and again start loop

Comment: can you paste code where you give cycle for images on which basis?

Comment: well I just start from the middle of the RecyclerView. So that user has a feeling of cyclic list.
But I'm open to any more efficient suggestions, thanks!